# Uploading/selecting multiple documents to upload at different instances

Tags: html, asp.net

Is there a way to make it so that a user could upload/select multiple documents when they select the Browse button multiple times?

For example, I have documents in the following folders:

- /folder1/documentA.doc
- /folder2/documentB.doc
- /folder2/documentC.doc

I currently have the following code:

```
<input id="docUpload" name="docUpload" multiple="multiple" type="file" value="" />
```

So if I chose documentA to upload, it would be selected. However, if I wanted to also upload docs B and C since they're in different locations, and I click on the Browse button again to do so, A is overwritten by C after I close the file browser prompt. How would you make it so that the list of documents are appended upon each button click?

I should also add that I'm using ASP.NET/MVC4.

If this can't be achieved through code (which I doubt), I'm also open to using jQuery plugins to bypass this.

Comment: I'm not going to lie, I don't understand why this was downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out that this behavior is regulated by the OS.

I made a workaround to allow the user to dynamically add a File Browser button to the form when they need to add multiple documents. It gets messy if there's a bunch of attachments, but it's a functional workaround.